# How do I convert strings separated by comma into dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, **input1, input2** variables and key_loc is list of keys for the dictionary,

**Input:**

```
input1='sam,geti,1234'
input2='jhon,somwhre,676966'
key_loc =['name','addr','phone']
```

I'm expecting the output in the below format.

**Output:**

```
output={'recod1:{'name':'sam','addr':'geti','phone':'12343'},
            'record2':{'name':'jhon','addr':'somewhre','phone':'676966'}}
```

How can we do this in python?

Comment: traverse the dictionary and use string.format method - http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Elaborate more and explain what you want to do. Also show what code you have and where you have problems with it.

Comment: it is not perfectly clear what is your input. Did you forgot to place quotes? Is your input a string, a text file or does the `input1` mean a variable?

Comment: @Skirmantas input is string only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume that you have a file or file-like object `input` containing the input lines you posted. Then you can use this code to parse it into a dictionary like this:

```
output = {}
for line in input:
    key, values = line.strip().split('=', 1)
    data = values.split(',')
    output['record' + key[5:]] = dict(name=data[0], addr=data[1], phone=data[2])
```

However, if you don't actually need the number from `input1` etc., consider using a `list` as the top-level object:

```
output = []
for line in input:
    values = line.strip().split('=', 1)[1]
    data = values.split(',')
    output.append(dict(name=data[0], addr=data[1], phone=data[2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use json library.

If you want to code yourself you should do something like:

```
output = {}
for indx, input in enumerate(inputs):
    name, addr, phone = input.split(",")
    output['record%i' %indx] = {'name':name, 'addr':addr, 'phone':phone}
```

where `inputs` is a list of your different inputs